# What is the regex pattern to extract this URL?

Tags: php, regex

I have a string:

```
href="javascript:KUBalloonOpen('0','http://img13.shop-pro.jp/PA01069/800/product/93163228.jpg',
```

I want to extract the URL from the above.  I tried using this expression:

```
$regex = "KUBalloonOpen('0','(.*)',";
```

But it does not work. What is the correct regexp?

Comment: `$regex = "~KUBalloonOpen\('0','(.*?)',~";` demo https://regex101.com/r/jO9wG2/1

Comment: you forget `?` (non-greedy) and `~` php modifier

Comment: your first answer does not work.

Comment: KUBalloonOpen\('0','(.*?)', work!!!

Comment: It is difficult to offer solutions when the problem
statement is simply, "it doesn't work".  Please [edit] your
question to give a more complete description of what you
expected to happen and how that differs from the actual
results.  See [ask] for hints on what makes a good
explanation.

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape single first `(` your regex:

```
$str ="href=\"javascript:KUBalloonOpen('0','http://img13.shop-pro.jp/PA01069/800/product/93163228.jpg',";
$regex = "/KUBalloonOpen\('0','(.*)\',/";
preg_match($regex, $str, $match);
```

`$match` returns:

```
Array (
    [0] => KUBalloonOpen('0','http://img13.shop-pro.jp/PA01069/800/product/93163228.jpg',
    [1] => http://img13.shop-pro.jp/PA01069/800/product/93163228.jpg
)
```